# How to guarantee rebirth in a western nation after death?

Tags: karma, rebirth

What karma must one do to achieve rebirth in a western nation?

Comment: Why do you want to know this? 

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to disappoint you but it is not possible to figure that out. Because Karma theory says that you can not figure out what karma will lead to exactly what result. You can only guess that good will lead to good and bad to bad.

Reference form Gita 4.17: You must understand the nature of all three—recommended action, wrong action, and inaction. The truth about these is profound and difficult to understand.

Answer (score 1):

जातस्य हि ध्रुवो मृत्युर्ध्रुवं जन्म मृतस्य च |
तस्मादपरिहार्येऽर्थे न त्वं शोचितुमर्हसि ||

The concept of Western nation is just a coined term to classify human races. But, human behaviour is same in all parts of world.

Births and deaths are unavoidable but they account for one Janma / half Janma / remaining Janmas for a human.

Karma is an integral part of human life as humans can never produce/ generate their own food for survival but has to be dependant on
A) modest plant species
B) conquering animal species

जन्म कर्म च मे दिव्यमेवं यो वेत्ति तत्त्वत: |
त्यक्त्वा देहं पुनर्जन्म नैति मामेति सोऽर्जुन

One who understands cycle(birth-death), and bounden duties(attached to bondage) as DIVYAM for him there is no further Janma.

Since practicing above by human is made complicated by "Survival of Fittest" theory in KaliYuga, there will be Punar Janmas due to more accumulative sins for majority sinners.